# running valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have not used valgrind before, but I need to use it to check memory leak. I ran the following command:

```
G_SLICE=always-malloc G_DEBUG=gc-friendly  valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=40 --log-file=valgrind.log example1
valgrind: example1: command not found
```

I followed instructions from this site:
[http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html](http://valgrind)

this is what the example1 file looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *x = malloc(100); /* or, in C++, "char *x = new char[100] */
    return 0;
}
```

I know valgrind is installed on my machine, regardless I ran the following command to make sure:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Can somebody pls. guide me how to get valgrind working....thx!

Comment: Is there definitely an executable called `example1` in your working directory?

Comment: valgrind runs against a binary, not source.  Have you compiled example1?

Comment: It seems the `example` program isn't found. You can verify by running both `valgrind` and `example`: the former won't do any harm but print a usage; the latter is your program. You might want to use `./example` instead.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: `s/example/example1/`

Comment: thanks guys, I ran it against source. absolutely new to valgrind :-(. I will make the fix and update post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to give it the path to the program you wanted to run! Replace `example1` with the path to the executable.

For example:

```
G_SLICE=always-malloc G_DEBUG=gc-friendly  valgrind -v \
  --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=40 \
  --log-file=valgrind.log ./example1
```